# running ionic application after it was working before : ionic serve

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-serve

i have a problem running my ionic application. `ionic serve` command terminates itself after building the application although it was working before

the result after executing the command:

```
E:\ionic\Test>ionic serve 
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser -
Ctrl+C to cancel
[11:52:28]  watch started ...
[11:52:28]  build dev started ...
[11:52:28]  clean started ...
[11:52:28]  clean finished in 5 ms
[11:52:28]  copy started ...
[11:52:28]  deeplinks started ...
[11:52:28]  deeplinks finished in 25 ms
[11:52:28]  transpile started ...
[11:52:31]  transpile finished in 2.75 s
[11:52:31]  preprocess started ...
[11:52:31]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[11:52:31]  webpack started ...
[11:52:31]  copy finished in 2.89 s
[11:52:36]  webpack finished in 5.22 s
[11:52:36]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[11:52:37]  sass finished in 769 ms
[11:52:37]  postprocess started ...
[11:52:37]  postprocess finished in 5 ms
[11:52:37]  lint started ...
[11:52:37]  build dev finished in 8.92 s
[11:52:37]  watch ready in 8.97 s
[11:52:37]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://10.101.60.135:8100
     DevApp: Test@8100 on DESKTOP-VJQV9GP


E:\ionic\Test>
```

it stopped executing as normal

Answer (score 1):

That happens very often when you have got more then one console open and running multiple instances of ionic

Comment: i have one console running at same time
i also restarted my machine to be more sure that there is only one console running

Answer (score 0):

Check if any other process is using the the same port 4200.